# Interpreting flat code and counting equations in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am having trouble locating the source of an additional unknown in a modelling project I am working on. I am getting an error saying I have 34 unknowns and 33 equations. I decided to look at the flattened code in Dymola, and while I can count the correct number of variables, I cannot find a way to reach the 33 equations. Below is the flattened code:

```
model HeatStorage
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Diameter D = 18.667 "Diameter";
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Height H = 20 "Height";
  parameter Boolean enable_losses = false "= true enable thermal losses with environment";
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.CoefficientOfHeatTransfer alpha = 1 
    "Constant heat transfer coefficient with the ambient";
  parameter Real L_start = 0 "Start value of level in %";
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Temperature T_start = Modelica.SIunits.Conversions.from_degC
    (300) "Start value of temperature";
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Temperature T_max = Modelica.SIunits.Conversions.from_degC
    (550) "Maximum tank temperature";
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Temperature T_set = Modelica.SIunits.Conversions.from_degC
    (300) "Tank Heater Temperature Set-Point";
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Power W_max = 3000000000.0 "Hot Tank Heater Capacity";
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Efficiency e_ht = 0.99 "Tank Heater Efficiency";
  parameter Boolean medium.preferredMediumStates = false "= true if StateSelect.prefer shall be used for the independent property variables of the medium";
  parameter Boolean medium.standardOrderComponents = true "If true, and reducedX = true, the last element of X will be computed from the other ones";
  input Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput Q_heater;
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Volume V_t = H*3.141592653589793*D^2/4;

  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium.MassFlowRate fluid_a.m_flow 
    "Mass flow rate from the connection point into the component";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.AbsolutePressure fluid_a.p "Thermodynamic pressure in the connection point";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.SpecificEnthalpy fluid_a.h_outflow 
    "Specific thermodynamic enthalpy close to the connection point if m_flow < 0";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.MassFraction fluid_a.Xi_outflow[0] 
    "Independent mixture mass fractions m_i/m close to the connection point if m_flow < 0";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.ExtraProperty fluid_a.C_outflow[0](start = 
    fill(1.0, size(fluid_a.C_outflow, 1))) "Properties c_i/m close to the connection point if m_flow < 0";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium.MassFlowRate fluid_b.m_flow 
    "Mass flow rate from the connection point into the component";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.AbsolutePressure fluid_b.p "Thermodynamic pressure in the connection point";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.SpecificEnthalpy fluid_b.h_outflow 
    "Specific thermodynamic enthalpy close to the connection point if m_flow < 0";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.MassFraction fluid_b.Xi_outflow[0] 
    "Independent mixture mass fractions m_i/m close to the connection point if m_flow < 0";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.ExtraProperty fluid_b.C_outflow[0](start = 
    fill(1.0, size(fluid_b.C_outflow, 1))) "Properties c_i/m close to the connection point if m_flow < 0";
  Modelica.SIunits.Temperature heat_PB.T "Port temperature";
  Modelica.SIunits.HeatFlowRate heat_PB.Q_flow "Heat flow rate (positive if flowing from outside into the component)";
  Modelica.SIunits.Temperature heat_DS.T "Port temperature";
  Modelica.SIunits.HeatFlowRate heat_DS.Q_flow "Heat flow rate (positive if flowing from outside into the component)";
  Modelica.SIunits.Volume V;
  Modelica.SIunits.Mass m;
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium.BaseProperties_D1.InputAbsolutePressure 
    medium.p(nominal = 100000.0, unit = "Pa", displayUnit = "bar", min = 0.0) 
    "Absolute pressure of medium";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium.BaseProperties_D1.InputMassFraction 
    medium.Xi[0](start = {}, unit = "1", min = 0.0, max = 1.0) "Structurally independent mass fractions";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium.BaseProperties_D1.InputSpecificEnthalpy 
    medium.h(unit = "J/kg") "Specific enthalpy of medium";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.Density medium.d "Density of medium";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.Temperature medium.T(start = 800, min = 573.15,
     max = 873.15) "Temperature of medium";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.MassFraction medium.X[2](start = {0.5, 0.5}) 
    "Mass fractions (= (component mass)/total mass  m_i/m)";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.SpecificInternalEnergy medium.u 
    "Specific internal energy of medium";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.SpecificHeatCapacity medium.R "Gas constant (of mixture if applicable)";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.MolarMass medium.MM "Molar mass (of mixture or single fluid)";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.AbsolutePressure medium.state.p 
    "Absolute pressure of medium";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.SpecificEnthalpy medium.state.h 
    "Specific enthalpy";
  Modelica.SIunits.Conversions.NonSIunits.Temperature_degC medium.T_degC = 
    Modelica.SIunits.Conversions.to_degC(medium.T) "Temperature of medium in [degC]";
  Modelica.SIunits.Conversions.NonSIunits.Pressure_bar medium.p_bar = 
    Modelica.SIunits.Conversions.to_bar(medium.p) "Absolute pressure of medium in [bar]";
  Modelica.SIunits.Area A;
  Modelica.SIunits.HeatFlowRate Q_losses;
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.AbsolutePressure state_i.p "Absolute pressure of medium";
  Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.SpecificEnthalpy state_i.h "Specific enthalpy";
  Modelica.SIunits.Power W_net;
  Modelica.SIunits.Power W_loss;
  output Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput L "Tank level in %";
  Modelica.SIunits.HeatFlowRate Q_PB "Heat Flow to PowerBlock";
  Modelica.SIunits.HeatFlowRate Q_desal "Heat Flow to Desalination";

// Equations and algorithms

  // Component medium
  // class SolarTherm.Media.MoltenSalt.MoltenSalt_base.BaseProperties
    // extends Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium.BaseProperties_D1
    equation
      if (medium.standardOrderComponents) then 
        medium.Xi = medium.X[1:0];
        medium.X = {0.5, 0.5};
        for i in (1:2) loop
          assert(medium.X[i] >= -1E-005 and medium.X[i] <= 1.00001, 
            "Mass fraction X["+       String(i, true, 0)+"] = "+       String(
            medium.X[i], true, 0)+"of substance "+{"NaNO3", "KNO3"}[i]+
            "\nof medium "+"MoltenSalt"+" is not in the range 0..1");
        end for;
      end if;
      assert(medium.p >= 0.0, "Pressure (= "+       String(medium.p, true, 0)+
        " Pa) of medium \""+"MoltenSalt"+"\" is negative\n(Temperature = "+
               String(medium.T, true, 0)+" K)");
    // end of extends 
  equation
    medium.d = SolarTherm.Media.MoltenSalt.MoltenSalt_Utilities.rho_T(medium.T);
    medium.h = medium.state.h;
    medium.u = medium.h-medium.p/medium.d;
    medium.MM = 0.091438;
    medium.R = 8.3144/medium.MM;
    medium.state.p = medium.p;
    medium.T = SolarTherm.Media.MoltenSalt.MoltenSalt_Utilities.T_h(medium.h);

  // This model
  // class PentakomoPlant.Storage.HeatStorage
  equation
    Q_losses =  -0.939*exp(Modelica.SIunits.Conversions.to_degC(medium.T)*
      0.005111)*1000*5/7;
    fluid_a.p = medium.p;
    fluid_b.p = medium.p;
    fluid_a.h_outflow = medium.h;
    fluid_b.h_outflow = medium.h;
    der(m) = fluid_a.m_flow+fluid_b.m_flow;
    m*der(medium.h)+der(m)*medium.h = Q_losses+Q_PB+Q_desal+W_net+fluid_a.m_flow
      *inStream(fluid_a.h_outflow)+fluid_b.m_flow*medium.h;
    V = m/medium.d;
    L = 100*(max(medium.T, T_set)-T_set)/(T_max-T_set);
    A = 6.283185307179586*(D/2)*H;
    W_net = Q_heater;
    W_loss = W_net/e_ht;
    heat_PB.Q_flow = Q_PB;
    heat_DS.Q_flow = Q_desal;
    heat_PB.T = medium.T;
    heat_DS.T = medium.T;

// Initial equations and algorithms

  // This model
  // class PentakomoPlant.Storage.HeatStorage
  initial equation
    medium.h = specificEnthalpy_Unique3(
      state_i);
    m = density_Unique4(
      state_i)*V_t;

end HeatStorage;
```

If someone could shed some light on exactly how the equations are counted from the flat code so as to help me locate my missing variable, I would be most appreciative!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the flattened code does not contain all the necessary information.

However, it is a good start and contains 27 equations:

- 2 binding equations
- 2 scalar equations in the extends Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium.BaseProperties_D1
- 7 equations in SolarTherm.Media.MoltenSalt.MoltenSalt_base.BaseProperties outside the base-class
- 16 equations in PentakomoPlant.Storage.HeatStorage.

But in addition there can at least be:

- Bindings of records (none in this case)
- Flow-variables in top-level public connectors; in this case I would assume it 2+2+1+1 (fluid_a, fluid_b, heat_PB, heat_DS).

The top-level public input Q_heater can be handled in two ways, and as I recall Dymola has used both variants: either it does neither contribute to unknowns nor to equations (seen as a known variable), or it adds one to both.

Comment: Right! Thank you very much! I totally forgot about the connection equations. That makes a lot more sense now.